# Device or gadget to read only comics/manga

Tags: e-reader, e-ink

I am in search of a device where I can **only (and only)** read manga or comics (color is preferable but I'm okay with black and white).

*Requirements:*

1. No youtube, browser, whatsapp, call facility! In short, a smartphone/tablet is not at all preferable as I have symptoms of [ADHD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention_deficit_hyperactivity_disorder) and it's hard for me to focus on one thing. But I really enjoy reading comics and manga. Usually, I was buying hardcopies but I can't keep on buying volumes one by one.
2. So, since a smartphone is a no, an e-reader comes into the picture. My initial search brings me to [Amazon Kindle](https://www.amazon.in/Staging-Product-Not-Retail-Sale/dp/B07FQ4Q5DH/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=kindle&qid=1603808229&sr=8-3). This piqued my interest as it involved **e-ink (it is pigment based and not light based, so it won't be that harmful for eyes)**

However, as per my findings, this (above) Kindle:

1. Doesn't support color
2. Doesn't give a good experience in zooming in and out as these so called pigments are reassembling every time ([Reddit Discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/kindle/comments/a0w06f/kindle_for_reading_manga/)  points to this fact)

Considering the constraints (which seem like an [outlier](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_enFR773IN773&sxsrf=ALeKk00xmdYLl14GWJP8Tz37cieQaE48EA%3A1603808640895&ei=gC2YX62dNtrWz7sPkbyhmAQ&q=outlier&oq=outlier&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIHCCMQyQMQJzIICAAQsQMQkQIyBwguELEDEEMyBQgAELEDMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAOgQIIxAnOgsIABCxAxCDARDJAzoCCC46BAguECc6DQgAELEDEIMBEMkDEEM6BAguEEM6BAgAEEM6BQguELEDOggIABDJAxCRAjoKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzoICC4QsQMQgwE6CggAEMkDEBQQhwI6BwgAEBQQhwJQmBVYyyVguCZoAnAAeACAAdQBiAHyCpIBBTAuNy4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwit3c_i_NTsAhVa63MBHRFeCEMQ4dUDCA0&uact=5)) can I get a recommendation on a device that:

1. is for the sole purpose of reading comics or manga
2. may or may not display in color (I am willing to invest in a color)
3. is affordable for me (within 90$ or 7000 INR)
4. may or may not use e-ink and if it is a tablet then it should be only for reading

Not that I have decided not to go for Kindle but the above discussion has reduced my interest in it. I am open to other e-readers also provided I can get them in India somehow.

Comment: what about the kindle paperwhite?

Comment: Kindle paperwhite is just different in ppi (pixels per inch), right? Could you clarify why you mentioned paperwhite? Is is out of personal experience or something else?

Comment: I mean, as it has more pixels, the resolution compared to the basic version of kindle  is definitely better. You should take it in mind as you will be looking at drawings all the time(if you will read manga only). Also the "light" of the display is a little bit better in the paperwhite version.